# Why sqrt in global scope is much slower than std::sqrt in MinGW?

Tags: c++, performance, function, mingw, sqrt

Consider the following code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

const int COUNT = 100000000;

int main()
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= COUNT; ++i)
        sum += sqrt(i);
    printf("%f\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

It runs 5.5s on my computer. However, if I change `sqrt` into `std::sqrt`, It will run only 0.7s.

I know that if I use `sqrt`, I'm using the function from C library, and if I use `std::sqrt`, I'm using the one in `<cmath>`.

But `<cmath>` doesn't define one for `int`, and if I change the type of `i` into `double`, they will run for equal speed. So the compiler isn't optimizing for `int`. This seems to only happen to `sqrt` in Windows.

So why is `std::sqrt` much faster than `sqrt`, but not other functions? And why in Linux they are not?

Comment: What is the compiler version and is this MinGW(.org) or MinGW-w64?

Comment: C++11 adds support for integer arguments to `std:sqrt`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt

Comment: Obviously if you are doing math with `double`s, it's going to take a noticeably longer time to run than with just `int`s.

Comment: @PaulR but doesn't that just cast the integer parameter to `double` (at least according to cppreference, or maybe I misunderstand it) which is equivalent to what would happen with `::sqrt`?

Comment: Have you looked at the generated machine code?

Comment: And your compiler compilation options are ... ?  When you post that a particular piece of code is slow/fast, you should post the compiler and compiler options used to build your example.  Otherwise it's a waste of time speculating what the issue is.

Comment: I compiled it with `g++ test.cpp -o test`, no optimization flag. I've tested it with the compiler from mingw.org, both 32bit and 64bit. I'm not using C++11.

Comment: @yyt16384 - No optimizations == meaningless results.

Comment: @yyt16384 How about you try it with optimisations and if the difference persists show some assembly (`-S` for gcc)?

Comment: @yyt16384: "I'm not using C++11" - that doesn't mean your library isn't. My version of GCC includes the new overload whether or not you specify C++11.

Comment: @rsethc: Honestly, it's only "obvious" with the right knowledge. My wife couldn't tell, for example. At the same time a lot of stuff that is "obvious" to her is egyptian hieroglyphs to me. As such, I consequently removed "obviously" from my grammar, because "obviousness" is always and always dependant on context and knowledge that is not in your genes, and it's never a reason at all. I go so far to say that using "obvious" often indicates lack of knowledge, actually, or lack of explanation skills.

Comment: @phresnel: I would consider it blatantly obvious compared to "it's the way the machine handles instructions generated in a namespace versus compiled to be optimized for the global scope" which is nonsense. (Things in namespaces are not, to my knowledge, treated any differently than things not in namespaces.)

Comment: @rsethc: It is obvious that if this is universally obvious, then the question asked here does not exist. Btw, it's totally, utterly and blatantly obvious to me that things are handled equally, never mind how deeply they are nested w.r.t. namespaces. To you, it's obviously not. Get my point?

Comment: @phresnel Alright good point that the question wouldn't be here, but no what I said was that they *are* treated the same. But yes I get the point, I suppose it's obvious to me but not the asker.

Comment: @rsethc: More specifically, you wrote that _to your knowledge_, they are treated the same. So obviously, it's not that obvious. Anyways, have a nice sunday :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the typical situation in which the `-fdump-tree-*` switch can give some insight into what is going on:

```
g++ -fdump-tree-optimized example1.cc
```

and you get the `example1.cc.165t.optimized` file. Somewhere inside:

```
<bb 3>:
_5 = (double) i_2;
_6 = sqrt (_5);
sum_7 = sum_1 + _6;
i_8 = i_2 + 1;
```

The compiler (gcc v4.8.3) is doing the math with `double`s.

Replacing `sqrt` with `std::sqrt` what you get is:

```
<bb 3>:
_5 = std::sqrt<int> (i_2);
sum_6 = sum_1 + _5;
i_7 = i_2 + 1;
```

Now it uses a different sqrt overload for integers (`i_2` is `int` and `sum_6` is `double`).

As Mike Seymour says in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547095/why-sqrt-in-global-scope-is-much-slower-than-stdsqrt-in-mingw#comment41717768_26547095), GCC uses the new overload whether or not you specify C++11.

Anyway under Linux there isn't a sensible performance difference between the two implementations.

Under Windows (MinGW) this is different since [`sqrt(double)` calls into `msvcrt`](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/message/27432041/).