# Why sqrt become much faster without -O2 in g++ on my computer?

Tags: c++, performance, g++, sqrt

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

const int COUNT = 1000000000;

int main()
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= COUNT; ++i) {
        sum += sqrt(i);
    }
    printf("%f\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Without `-O2`, it runs only 2.9s on my computer, while it runs 6.4s with `-O2`.

My computer is Fedora 23, with g++ 5.3.1.

I have tried the same thing on Ubuntu 14.04 (with g++ 4.8), it doesn't have the problem (all 6.4s).

Comment: And how did you arrive at these timing results - there's no timing mechanism in your code?

Comment: @kfsone Presumably with the `time` command. You don't need to create your own timing mechanism if a perfectly good one is already readily available.

Comment: I get similar results....!?! (also with GCC 6.1.0)

Comment: My 5-year-old macbook air (yeah, kinda weak) running apple's llvm clang gets 10.352s without -O2, 7.687 with -O2. I feel its probably worth your time to compile-to-asm and inspect the code. My inspection of the clang-generated asm shows the optimized version partially unrolls the loop. It would be interesting to see what gcc is doing.

Comment: With `-O`, GCC uses a `sqrtsd %xmm0,%xmm0` instruction. With `-O2`, GCC uses a `sqrtsd %xmm0,%xmm1` instruction, which on my system increases the time by 2s. If I take the `-O2` assembly code, change that, and change the remaining `%xmm1` references to `%xmm0`, the time goes down by 2s again. But I have no idea why it's faster, nor why if it's faster, GCC doesn't use the faster version.

Comment: Show full compiler flags that you used

Comment: @kfsone Just as hvd said, I use `time`.

Comment: @M.M Just `g++ tmp -o tmp` and `g++ tmp -o tmp -O2`, nothing more.

Comment: Probably better never-than-late, but [godbolt.org](http://godbolt.org) is an *awesome* place to inspect asm-generation from different compilers (or same compilers with different optimization levels). I highly recc you put it on your favorites bar for future reference.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: I'm 99% sure this question is a duplicate of [Why sqrt in global scope is much slower than std::sqrt in MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547095/why-sqrt-in-global-scope-is-much-slower-than-stdsqrt-in-mingw). It seems to point out that the C++11 sqrt int overload is faster than the built-in sqrt (implemented by the C runtime, in this case glibc). Someone decided to downvote my answer anyways.

Comment: @user6292850 That downvote was mine, and I downvoted because it's wrong and my comment on this question already showed that it's wrong well before you posted your answer.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the gcc optimizer. Clang doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: @hvd Maybe I'm missing something. Can you explain how that's related to why my answer is wrong?

Comment: @user6292850 If I'm able to see the difference in performance with exactly zero change to which functions get called, the problem can't be in which functions get called.

Comment: @hvd I think the reason why we're seeing a difference is because you used `-O`, which is not the same as no optimizations.

Comment: @user6292850 The performance with `-O0` and `-O` was the same. I used `-O` because the generated assembly code with `-O` was much closer to the generated assembly code with `-O2`, making it easier to pin-point the specific instructions having a problem.

Comment: Perhaps another point of interest: with the exact same compiler, exact same source code, exact same distribution and hence exact same generated program, but running on older computer with older CPU ("model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 650 @ 3.20GHz", from somewhere around 2011, IIRC), there isn't any big difference between `-O0`/`-O`/`-O2` performance. Is GCC perhaps simply optimising for older CPUs?

Answer (score 3):

Naive version uses call to glibc `sqrt` function.

Optimized version uses SSE `sqrtsd` instruction. But after instruction has completed, it checks that result value is not a NaN. If result value is NaN then it calls glibc `sqrt` function to setup proper error flags (see manual page for `math_error(7)`). See [Why does compiler generate additional sqrts in the compiled assembly code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854256/why-does-compiler-generate-additional-sqrts-in-the-compiled-assembly-code) for detailed explanation.

Why gcc thinks that this is faster? Nobody knows. If you are sure that your numbers don't generate NaNs, use `-fno-math-errno` compile option.

Comment: With `-ffast-math`, this check is also removed and generates faster code.

Comment: Except that at `-O`, GCC does use the `sqrtsd` instruction (with different operands), yet achieves better performance than at `-O2`.

Comment: @hvd , you are correct. Seems that branch prediction is somehow involved? `-O2` generates `jp <block with call to sqrt>` and `-O` uses `jnp <block without call to sqrt>`.

Comment: I don't think so, see my comment on the question, but I have no idea what would be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating the assembly may turn up some answers, but the easiest way to see the difference in code is to do `-fdump-tree-optimized`. The issue seems to be related to `sqrt` overloads, namely the one provided by the C library `sqrt(double)` and C++11 `sqrt(int)`. The latter seems to be faster, and GCC doesn't seem to care whether you use `-std=c++11` or prefix `std::` to `sqrt` or not.

Here's an excerpt for the dump with `-O2` or `-O` (`-O` with no number enables optimizations, to disable all optimizations, omit `-O`):

```
  int i;
  double sum;
  double _9;
  __type _10;

  <bb 2>:

  <bb 3>:
  # sum_15 = PHI <sum_6(3), 0.0(2)>
  # i_16 = PHI <i_7(3), 1(2)>
  _9 = (double) i_16;
  _10 = __builtin_sqrt (_9);
  sum_6 = _10 + sum_15;
  i_7 = i_16 + 1;
  if (i_7 == 1000000001)
    goto <bb 4>;
  else
    goto <bb 3>;
```

Then without `-O2`:

```
  <bb 4>:
  _8 = std::sqrt<int> (i_2);
  sum_9 = sum_1 + _8; 
  i_10 = i_2 + 1; 
  goto <bb 3>;
```

Notice it uses `std::sqrt<int>`. For the skeptical, please see [Why sqrt in global scope is much slower than std::sqrt in MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547095/why-sqrt-in-global-scope-is-much-slower-than-stdsqrt-in-mingw)